# Move a Webform between sites

Tags: 8, webforms

I built a few webforms on a Drupal 8 install. I see how to export the webform in YAML via the export tab on the webform.

How do I import that YAML into another site to re-create that webform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to go to */admin/config/development/configuration/single/import*, select *Webform* and paste the YAML.

More information: [Configuration Managment](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management).